# Read files using cmd and insert into c++

Tags: c++, batch-file, cmd

I need help with this task

1) File.bat will open program.exe written in c++

2) Using .bat i need to read data from 3-4 files in folder data, then insert it into my c++ file.

3) When program stops calculating i need to insert results to the .txt files  in folder output.

Example of files

Folder Data

Data1.txt

```
0, 0, 20, 0, 10, 30, 10, 15
there will be more under
```

Data2.txt

```
4, 2, 10, -4, 10, 20, 0, -300
there will be more under
```

Program below will check if point is in triangle or outside

Program.exe

```
#include < bits / stdc++.h >
  using namespace std;
float wspolrzedne(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3) 
{
  return abs((x1 * (y2 - y3) + x2 * (y3 - y1) + x3 * (y1 - y2)) / 2.0);
}

bool wewnatrz(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int x, int y) 
{
  float A = wspolrzedne(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
  float A1 = wspolrzedne(x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3);
  float A2 = wspolrzedne(x1, y1, x, y, x3, y3);
  float A3 = wspolrzedne(x1, y1, x2, y2, x, y);
  return (A == A1 + A2 + A3);
}

int main() 
{
  if (wewnatrz(input.txt))
    printf("Inside");
  else
    printf("Outside");
    insert into output.txt
  return 0;
}
```

Folder output

Output1.txt

```
Inside
there will be more under
```

Output2.txt

```
Outside
there will be more under
```

bat file

```
@echo off
:menu
cls
echo ========MENU=======
echo === 1. Start   ====
echo === 2. Info    ====
echo === 3. Backup  ====
echo === 4. Exit    ====
echo ===================
set /p select="Select 1,2,3,4: "
IF %select%==1 goto opt1
IF %select%==2 goto opt2
IF %select%==3 goto opt3
IF %select%==4 goto exit

:opt1
echo Data from files will be collected and processed.
????????
pause
goto menu
:opt2
echo This program checks if point is in or outside triangle
pause
goto menu
:opt3
echo Your backup is on the way
Xcopy  %cd%  %cd%\Backup  /M /E /G /H /Y
pause
goto menu
:exit
echo Bye!
pause
```

How i can connect it all? I don't have idea.

Comment: Recommendation: Burn whatever you are using as a C++ programming reference and replace it with [a good beginners book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Once you have worked your way through the first few chapters of this book return to this problem.

Comment: **Recommended reading:** _[Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)_

Comment: Your batch file never executes your executable.

Comment: I suggest not using `set /P` for a choice menu, use the command `choice` which is designed for such tasks. For more details see [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) But I do not really understand why a batch file is used at all. You wrote an executable in C++. Everything done in the batch file can be also done with C++ code much better and faster. So there is no need for a batch file at all in my point of view.

Comment: Because profesor said we have to use batch as menu and programm in c++